# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm targeting to create an array from the data I get from API. However it keeps showing me the error of `cannot read property 'push' of undefined Javascript`.

Can anyone point me the way out?

Here is the code:

```
 myService.getData().then(function (res) {
            $scope.resoureceGroupsRawData = res.data;
            //declare an array already...
            $scope.resourceGroupItems = new Array();

        }, function(error) {
           throw error;
        }).then(function() {
            _.forEach($scope.resoureceGroupsRawData, function(text, idx) {
                var item = {};
                item.id = idx++;
                item.label = text;
                //why it says resourceGroupItems is null?
                $scope.resouceGroupItems.push(item);
            });
        }, function(err) {

        });
```

Comment: You are missing the second "r" from `resouceGroupItems` on the line that is having the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typos bro,
you mispelled resource in few places.

```
myService.getData().then(function (res) {
            $scope.resourceGroupsRawData = res.data;
            //declare an array already...
            $scope.resourceGroupItems = new Array();

        }, function(error) {
           throw error;
        }).then(function() {
            _.forEach($scope.resourceGroupsRawData, function(text, idx) {
                var item = {};
                item.id = idx++;
                item.label = text;
                //why it says resourceGroupItems is null?
                $scope.resourceGroupItems.push(item);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            //TODO need add error page here
        });
```

Comment: you declare as `$scope.resourceGroupItems = new Array();`  and used as  `$scope.resouceGroupItems.push(item);`. missed an `r` @catlovespurple

Comment: While correct, this answer is not helpful. Please add explanation.